# Looking for ways to program a calendar (for gui) for bookings and appointments for hotel managment system

Tags: java, calendar

As part of our "Software Engineering and Project Management" course assignment, we got to do a hotel management software. So fat it's been going great, however, I do have issue with one of the features: How to visually represent all bookings and/or appointments in calendar...

At first my idea was to save all Bookings from DB in an arraylist, and then with use of JTable create a table where rows represent Rooms and columns represent Days. Then with the help of a loop I would check every column, and then ask from array where bookings are stored, if at that day some of the bookings begin. if so I would highlight the cell. However our tutor told me not to do so, because it's just way too much unnecessary work and instead just use java calendar api to solve this.

The thing is, I've been googling but I haven't found any helpful tutorials or topics which would help me figure out how to do what I want. Unfortunately due to my time capacity right now, I can't afford to spend a whole day looking and testing something which usually end up not working as we want it.

In short, we need to visually represent active bookings/appointments in calendar and we're looking for the fastest and simplest way to do so.

Comment: You and your teacher have probably misunderstood each other. The calendar API has nothing to do with GUI. Nothing prevents your solution (to the GUI problem) to use the calendar API (to know if a booking is at the same date as the one displayed in your JTable column). Talk to your teacher again. Maybe he just doesn't want you to implement a GUI, and a simple textual output is sufficient. A GUI is indeed something that takes time to implement, and that's maybe not what the teacher wants you to do.

Comment: @JBNizet It is. I got to program "Room occupancy" feature. In DAOs I only have two methods, one which returns array with all Bookings (which have two Date variables bTo and bFrom) and one which returns Bookings for a specific Room. Now in GUI part I have to visually represent these bookings in a timeline. Though there is no strict policy on how it should look, we have all agreed that this feature should literally be a calendar, a table-like visual representation for room occupancy.

Comment: Then do it as you want. Swing doesn't have any built-in calendar GUI component.

Comment: [This](http://jaret.de/timebars/tb_screenshots.html) might useful.

Comment: I don't know if it will help you with the visual aspect, but this link shows how you can create a jagged array for a calendar quickly. You may be able to use it to iterate through and locate events.

 http://www.djekldevelopments.co.uk/microsoft-visual-basic-net-programmers-cookbook/source/6797final/lib0059.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're smart, you can get the db engine to do most of the work. Consider this untested MySQL query:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, DATEDIFF(booking_date, '2012-05-20') AS col FROM bookings WHERE booking_date BETWEEN '2012-05-20' AND '2012-05-27' GROUP BY booking_date;

This will give you the column and the number of bookings on that day. From there you just have to loop through the results and complete the table.

Edit: If you don't have db access you should store the data in a HashMap so you have O(1) lookup rather than O(n) each time.

Answer (score -3):

you could create a gmail account and use the calendar provided with your account. Then you can use google's API to import that calendar to a web page

Comment: Thanks, but that's not very useful and is missing the point of the assignment.